# "Cannot find interface declaration for <class>"

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-category

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GA6PP.jpg)

I'm having quite a hard time setting up a category on a class I made. From what I've read, Objective-C allows you to create a category on *any* class, not just closed-source ones. (It honestly wouldn't make sense any other way.)

Of course I can add the category messages to the actual class file, but I want to keep them separate (as the category is an uncommonly special use of a class that can be used very generally). I want to share the class, but keep the category private... anyway.

I've stripped down the category to just show the issue at hand. I (currently) get four errors on the first category message. The number of errors I receive on that line is directly proportional to how many times it is references, but it is not an even rise. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: What you've written looks correct to me. I've done similar things in my code. My guess is that maybe this is some other issue that's confusing the compiler. Does "ByteCollection.h" have a proper @end in it, for example? Or is there anything else that could be wrong with either "ByteCollection.h" or anything it includes?

Comment: Not that I can see; Xcode doesn't point out anything and I implement the entire interface. What exactly dictates a 'proper @end'?

Comment: Another possibility is that the compiler isn't finding "ByteCollection.h" when you import it. If that file's in a different folder (in the filesystem, not in Xcode's yellow-folder "groups"), you may need to set up search paths in the project settings so it can be found.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure it's nothing to do with the cause of your problem, but by convention ObjC category names are capitalized.

Comment: Capitalization: fixed - thanks ;) Also, all source files are in the same folder (flat). But, I am wondering if that could be the issue. I've previously had problems with Xcode simply not importing files that I ask it to import. Does anyone know if there is a surefire way to determine this?

Comment: By any chance, can you show Resources.h?

Comment: @rickster Good point but I think the compiler would throw an error on `#import` (file not found). The strange thing is that even if he didn't `#import` the header file, the error should be on `@interface` line and not in the method declaration. Did you try to clean & rebuild?

Comment: [`Resources.h`](http://pastebin.com/dDihYE0Q) is just a list of import statements and I have removed all references to it in attempts to address this issue.

Comment: Tried the clean and rebuild - no luck.

Comment: @vermiculus: Are you sure? You removed the import from ByteCollection.h and you still got the exact same error? Because as I said in my answer, it explains the error perfectly.

Comment: Trust me, I'm sure. `ByteCollection.h` now imports nothing (except for the prefix header, which imports Foundation and #defines a few types).  `ByteCollection.m` imports its header and `mem.h`, a C utility file for working with memory on an even lower level than C makes easy. `ByteCollection+Words.h` imports `ByteCollection.h`, and finally `ByteCollection+Words.m` imports its header file. There are zero circular dependencies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Resources.h file, which is imported by ByteCollection.h, imports ByteCollection+words.h. So when ByteCollection+words.h imports ByteCollection.h, this results in a circular dependency†. The simplest way to break a circular dependency is to move one of the imports to the implementation file rather than the header. It looks like this should be possible with Resources.h.

† You might be wondering, why is it a problem if you have a circular dependency? Well, the #import directive literally just textually includes the file you specify, just like if you copy-pasted. It also intelligently doesn't include a file twice, because that would create duplicate code. But this means that when File A says "I want File B to go before me" and File B says "I want File A to go before me," one of them is going to be disappointed, and that leads to errors like the one you're getting here.

Comment: Yes, it does import `ByteCollection+Words.h`, but I've had issues with circular inclusion before and will never scratch my head for that mistake again! XD There are no circular inclusion issues. I never even import `Resources.h` anywhere in my source files. (Used to, but not anymore.) I even commented out the specific import for good measure with no effect.

Thanks though :)